# Why cookie in res headers is not set in browser?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, cors, setcookie

I run backend at `http://localhost:4000` and frontend at `http://localhost:3000`. In server (Express) I set `cors` policy as:

```
  app.use( cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  }));
```

But the cookie is not set. After the request

```
POST /graphql HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 373
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36
content-type: application/json
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost:3000/register
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: et-EE,et;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

I got back response headers with correct(?) `Set-Cookie`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 122
ETag: W/"7a-3NezKfolEhPugNDLsBCed9Xgfzk"
Set-Cookie: lirr=s%3A9JJT7_mt6W-zSWkg-DKkBmxK6O-i8bH3.1k88dMMeintjdSUMV6ig1DK5u4vgdYh4rnmtufww7nw; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 27 Nov 2021 09:31:14 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Date: Fri, 27 Nov 2020 09:31:14 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

I tried with Chrome and Firefox and neither set the cookie. I don't see a flaw in my setup, headers seem fine. What am I missing?

**IN addition**

If I let set cookie from the backend (exposed as Graphql API, accessed with Graphql playground), it **works fine** with such req headers:

```
POST /graphql HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 323
accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36
content-type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:4000
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost:4000/graphql
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: et-EE,et;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

As far I notice, 3 lines (as expected) differ:

```
Origin: http://localhost:4000
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Referer: http://localhost:4000/graphql
```

A reponse is pretty same as frontend's:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 75
ETag: W/"4b-Ud8RJ2O7ZjwpTxFNSAQi92iV20w"
Set-Cookie: lirr=s%3A9CYQjFpVwG69-ojwqlk-FJWVNC02DMJP.Prt8U5%2Bcco9ktEL27JoOkAlACGKS%2Fy1NHfgugPypl00; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 27 Nov 2021 10:32:37 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Date: Fri, 27 Nov 2020 10:32:37 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

I don't understand, why the browser does not set the cookie through the frontend...

Comment: How are you sending the request? Could you add the code to your post.

Comment: I use `URQL` to send graphql queries to backend server. I got solved the practical part (added `fetchOptions: {credentials: 'include'}` `urql`'s `createClient`), but I still don't understand the theoretical mechanism behind it. The headers are still same with or without credentials set, even for preflight OPTIONS request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Server side check

Your setting looks fine to me.

```
  app.use( cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  }));
```

I suggest testing your code with some API tool like POSTman which **enables CORS request as default**. If it works with POSTman, then your server side code has no problem.

#### Browser issue with CORS + Cookie

Simply, CORS request is nothing but XMLHttpRequest to different domain. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

According to the following doc,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

> In addition, this flag is also used to indicate when **cookies are to be ignored** in the response. **The default is false**. XMLHttpRequest from a **different domain cannot set cookie values for their own domain unless withCredentials is set to true before making the request**. The third-party cookies obtained by setting withCredentials to true will still honor same-origin policy and hence can not be accessed by the requesting script through document.cookie or from response headers.

Browser will not accept/transfer cookies via CORS request(XMLHttpRequest) unless you enable it.

```
xhr.withCredentials = true;
```

#### Example via browser console

```
//from http://localhost:3000
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'http://localhost:4000/get-cookie-url';
   
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.withCredentials = true; // enable browser to transfer cookies
xhr.onload = function(e){
  console.log(e)
};
xhr.send();
```

#### Cookie transfer

To illustrate, cookie transfer is **similar to handshake**.

Both side need to initiate for handshake. If one side(server) initiates and the other(client) does not, handshake will not happen.

When **Server** initiates cookie transfer,

```
//Server response header
//Server will response with "Set-Cookie" header when browser requests
...
Set-Cookie: lirr=xxxx; ...
...
```

When **Client(Browser)** initiates cookie transfer,

```
//Client request header
//Client will request with "Cookie" header 
...
Cookie: lirr=xxxx; ....
...
```

Comment: Through Postman I got cookies set. Good idea, thank you! Next, your links gave me some hints to look for "credentials" client side. From https://github.com/benawad/how-to-debug-cookies I got idea how to add "withCredentials" to my client-side. And if I add, cookies are set as needed. BUT: i don't see any difference in headers, even not in preflight ones. So practical half is solved, but theoretical is still not clear to me.

Comment: @w.k , well done, it is great to hear you sorted some of it out. To illustrate, cookie transfer is very similar to handshake. I will update the above post with some details.

Comment: I think, I got it clear after reading more about CORS: I use `urql`'s `createClient` function, which uses JS `Request()` for HTTP requests. And `Request` has default 'same-origin' for `credentials`. If I not set it client-side to 'include', it just ignores cookies which does not have set by orginal origin. I assumed, that this info is included to the headers, but they have managed in client-side. Thank you once more, your hints lead me to solution.

Comment: @w.k , awesome , Thank you, your issue was good review for me as well. Since netscape time, web browser standard has been changed a lot. Also our tools/frameworks abstract underneath. Because of that, we got confused sometimes.